# php outlook calendar event with attachment issue

Tags: php, email, outlook, vcalendar

We have problem with mail attachment. Currently I am working for outlook calendar event with attachment. Every thing is fine and I got mail with attachment, but I received email only if the attachment is less than 10Kb. Otherwise I didn't received any mails.  If I use
 `chunk_split()` 
function than I received email with more than 10Kb file attachment, but only some part of the file( I tested with text file I got first few lines only) received.

I checked the server, and it have capability to send large file.

Here is my code. Please help me guys ..

```
if($filename_path ==''){
     $filename_path = './Upload/Cal_temp/'.$filename2;
     $filename_pathnew = base_url().'Upload/Cal_temp/'.$filename2;
}

$calendid = $this->input->post('calendar_id');

$handle = fopen($filename_path, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename_path));
fclose($handle);

$finaldata =  base64_encode($contents);
 $finaldata = chunk_split($finaldata);

$dataone = filesize($filename_path);
$datatwo = strlen($contents); 


define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis');
$fromname = 'example';   

$vcal  = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
$vcal .= "VERSION:2.0\n";
$vcal .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\n"; //requied by Outlook
$vcal .= "X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\n";
$vcal .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
/* $vcal .= "STATUS:".$this->input->post('status')."\n"; */
$vcal .= "DTSTART:".date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($s_date.' '.$s_time))."\n";
$vcal .= "DTEND:".date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($e_date.' '.$e_time))."\n";
$vcal .= "SUMMARY: ".$desc_txt." ".$empname['firstname'].' '.$empname['lastname']."-".$clientname['firstname'].' '.$clientname['lastname']."\n";
$vcal .= "DESCRIPTION: Your appointment has been updated for ".$empname['firstname'].' '.$empname['lastname']." with ".$clientname['firstname'].' '.$clientname['lastname']." with regard to ".$jobnumber." and ".$taskcode." between ".$s_date.' '.$s_time." and ".$e_date.' '.$e_time."\r\n\r\n";
$vcal .= "ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=".$filename2.":".$finaldata."=\n";

$vcal .= "CLASS:PUBLIC\n";
$vcal .= "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n";
$vcal .= "UID:". $calendid ."\n";
$vcal .= "SEQUENCE:0\n";


$vcal .= "SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:excel\n";
$vcal .= "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
            X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
            X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
            X-MS-OLK-ALLOWEXTERNCHECK:TRUE
            X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
            X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
            BEGIN:VALARM
            TRIGGER:-PT15M
            ACTION:DISPLAY
            DESCRIPTION:Reminder
            END:VALARM
            END:VEVENT
            END:VCALENDAR";


$headers = "From: ".$fromemail."\r\nReply-To: "; 
$headers .= "\r\nMIME-version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=\"utf-8\"";
$headers .= "\r\n Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nX-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0"; 
//$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$subject = 'Your appointment has been updated';

mail($email, $subject, $vcal, $headers);
```

I tried with **headers** almost all types, but no luck.

Comment: @ToddHorst No ToddHorst. I'm just walk away from this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the space in front of the header could be the problem

```
-$headers .="\r\n Content-Transfer-Encoding:...
+$headers .="\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding:...
```